# What is #Number in Java bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

I wrote a simple java source like this :

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

and converted it to the equivalent bytecode with the javap -c command

```
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main {
  public Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String Hello World!
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

What are **#1,#2,#3,#4**,... ?

When and Why would you use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `#` symbols refer to the constant pool of the class, if you decompile verbosely using

```
javap -c -s -verbose Main.class
```

you will get their definition in the `Constant pool` section

```
Constant pool:
 #1 = Methodref          #6.#15         // java/lang/Object."<init>"()V
 #2 = Fieldref           #16.#17        //  
 = String             #18            // Hello World!
#4 = Methodref          #19.#20        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
#5 = Class              #21            // Main
#6 = Class              #22            // java/lang/Object
#7 = Utf8               <init>
#8 = Utf8               ()V
#9 = Utf8               Code
#10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
#11 = Utf8               main 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#x` refers to an entry in the class [constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4). The actual value of the entry is printed in the comment.

To also view the constant pool use `javap -c -verbose ...`